# setBackgroundDrawable is not changing the LayoutBackground

Tags: android, drawable, android-linearlayout

I have seen several instances of this question on here and the provided solutions dont seem to work.

My goal :  Update the background of my LinearLayout depending on what color i get back from a database query.

What I have so far:

```
if(teamc=="black"){
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackbackground);
    Toast.makeText(TeamActivity.this,teamc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    teamColor.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

Team color is defined as

```
teamColor = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.teamcolor);
```

What is happening is that the Toast is appearing just fine but the background is not changing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that that toast is showing and not other toast? Because you try to check a `String` if it's equal to another `String` by using == operator and that is wrong.

You have to use `.equals()` method to make a comparison between two Objects.

Comment: No it's not :), these things happen to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

It is really strange if Toast is working but background is not changing.

```
Try using teamc.equals("black"){}
```

or

```
teamColor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackbackground);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make directly teamColor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackbackground);

Answer (score 0):

call the invalidate() of the LinearLayout using teamColor object after set the background

```
teamColor.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use a WebView to display a web page, when the page is scale fits well but now are whites spaces on each side of the page, I can change the background to black color??